# Secure url parameter

Tags: php, regex

ok,Let me explain you step by step,Point is im new for this developments.

php files in my cproject directory :
allproducts.php
watch.php

in allproducts.php im displaying all the products available in the database. and every products has it own url. In my watch.php im displaying certain  data according to a parameter comes from the allproducts.php page.

in my allproducts.php page i have this url :

http://localhost/cproject/watch?v=

url looks like something like this :

localhost/cproject/watch?v=J46TKlqSw3Gt4sk

at the moment i wrote a rewriterule for make watch.php in to "watch"

now what i want is to get rid of this "?" mark in to "/" and "v= " into "/"
so i want my rul to looks like this 
localhost/cproject/watch/J46TKlqSw3Gt4sk

i hope now u do understand what i want to do actually ?
if i suddenly explain you what i have on my .htaccess file for this watch.php 
i have this line of code

> RewriteRule ^watch watch.php [NC,L]

Comment: You can send post request and get in php file with `$_POST['param_name']` OR `$_REQUEST['param_name']`. OR you can do URL rewrite using htaccess.

Comment: yes im asking how with an examples because i dont know how to do this

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: which codes do you want me to share ?

Comment: Whether you use a GET parameter or a parameter in the URL it does NOT change how hackable/injectable your site is. Sure if you only allow the characters from a-z in the URL then it's harder to inject, but you need to control your injections on a lower level. If it's for file access, check the filename being accessed and if it's for SQL injection use prepared statements and bind your variables.

Comment: So do you say links like this can never ever inject by hackers ? llocalhost/cproject/watch?v=J46TKlqSw3Gt4sk

but it can directly access the database through this v= parameter.Because it is checking weather the data on this v= parameter exists in the database or not ?

Answer (score 0):

> You have to use .htaccess for doing url this.

**.htaccess file code**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

For PHP version less than 5.2.6 try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

If you need to get the parameter from the url then use:

**javascript**

```
var str = "http://localhost/cproject/watch?v=J46TKlqSw3Gt4sk";
var param = str.split("=")[1];
alert(param);
```

**Result**

> J46TKlqSw3Gt4sk

**With the new url**

```
var str = "http://localhost/cproject/J46TKlqSw3Gt4sk";
var param = str.split("/");
alert(param[param.length - 1]);
```

**Result**

> J46TKlqSw3Gt4sk

Comment: Thank you,But what i want is to get a url like i have mentioned above and get the parameter in a different page

Comment: you can design the url like this but not works. for working with this type of url you need to add `.htaccess` file in your hosting space and have some code to control the url.

Comment: can you please help me to write the necessary codes /

Comment: what is this index.php and what is use for ?

Comment: it is default .htaccess code. For your url: `RewriteRule ^cproject/(.*) cproject/watch?v=$1 [NC]` as done by @PXgamer

Comment: i didnt still have a good understanding about this work, Can you please explain me more ?

Comment: I don't ever use `.htaccess` for my personal work, so i can't.

Answer (score 0):

For the .htaccess file you can use this RewriteRule which will forward the urls with just a `/` to the url with `/watch?v=`.

```
RewriteRule ^cproject/(.*) cproject/watch?v=$1 [NC]
```

For example:

Start URL `http://localhost/cproject/eeeeeeeaf`
End URL `http://localhost/cproject/watch?v=eeeeeeeaf`

> But what i want is to get a url like i have mentioned above and get the parameter in a different page

You can do this with PHP from the `/watch` file by using the `REQUEST_URI` element in the `$_SERVER[]` array.

For the PHP code you could do:

```
<?php
$request  = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$exploded = explode("/", $request);
$id       = $exploded[4];
echo $id;
?>
```

In regards to your additions to your question, it is easy to do as I have put above. Instead of what I have put, you can instead just use:

```
RewriteRule ^watch/(.*) watch.php?v=$1 [NC,L]
```

You can add this rule alongside your current rule (preferably after) and it should function as you require.

> now what i want is to get rid of this "?" mark in to "/" and "v= " into "/" so i want my rul to looks like this localhost/cproject/watch/J46TKlqSw3Gt4sk

The URL RewriteRule I provided will do this :)
Have you actually tested the rewrites you have been provided with?

Comment: do i need a derectory for this in a same name i called to the url in htaccess ?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean? Sorry.

Comment: Thanks , but my "watch" in this url is a specific page i have rewrite before.
in a example my real url for the "watch"  is like view_product.php .
So do you think this will work ?

Comment: This should work fine :) Just change the end url to `/cproject/view_product.php?v=eeeeaf` or you can use it as it is, just make sure this rule is after your first one :)

Comment: i didnt still have a good understanding about this work, Can you please explain me more ?

Comment: Which part are you asking for an explanation on?

Comment: let me open an new comment to explain you below